# Problems running bash script from incron

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, inotify, incron

I have a simple incron task setup to run a command whenever a particular .json file is written-to, then closed.

`/var/www/html/api/private/resources/myfile.json IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN NO LOOP /var/www/html/api/private/resources/run_service.sh`

I can see that whenever the file to written to, there is a syslog entry for the event, and the command that was triggered - along the lines of `<date> - incrond: CMD (/var/www/html/api/private/resources/run_service.sh)`.

But nothing seems to happen...

initially I thought this would be caused by an issue with the script, but replacing the script command to something simple such as `echo "hello world" > /tmp/mylog.log` still yields no output or results. I seem to have hit a brick wall with this one!

**Update**

Changing the incron command to read `"/bin/bash /var/www/html/api/private/resources/run_service.sh"` now seems to triggering the script correctly, as I can now get output from the script.

Comment: The things I'm trying to trigger work perfectly from command line. The attempt of a simple echo as detailed above was to rule out the possibility of the problem being caused by the differences between incron and CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple mistake on my part, despite all examples online showing that using the script as the command should run it, for me it only works if I explicitly call bash to execute it

```
"<my directory/file to watch> <trigger condition> /bin/bash /var/www/html/api/private/resources/run_service.sh
```